# How to make dynamic picker in react native functional component?

Tags: react-native, post, dynamic, mapping, picker

I have to to some task which is create a dynamic picker option. But I tried some options on internet and most of the options are explaint using class components. But I need to go with the functional component. The purpose of the creating picker is to select a product by its name.(So picker indicate its name on the labels). But inside this, I need to call post request with that selected product's ID, not it's name. So I also need to get Product ID as a input when selecting a option (as product Name) from picker.

Following is the `productDetails` finally gets on console.

```
  {"data": [{"accountCoordinatorEmail": null, "category": "edu", "createdAt": null, "createdBy": null,
     "customerEmail": "c@gmail.com", "modifiedAt": null, "modifiedBy": null, "productID": 111, 
"productName": "e-School", "projectManagerEmail": null},
```

So as  example I need to post productID = 111 as a input while selecting productName as a e-school from the picker. How should I implement that. I saw some mapping function in the class component examples. But I cant understand from class components.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


const ProductPicker = () => {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
    const [productDetails , setproductDetails] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getProductList();
    }, []);

    const getProductList = async () => {
         const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

        fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/customer/get-all-products", {

            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authentication': `Bearer ${token}`
            },
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => setproductDetails(json.data))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error))

    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Picker
                selectedValue={selectedValue}
                style={{height: 40, width: 150}}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                    setSelectedValue(itemValue);
                }}
            >
                
            </Picker>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 40,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});

export default ProductPicker;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs (https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker):

You need `<Picker.Item>` child components to render the list. This is where you would have seen the map function. One way to do this is by rendering a functional component as child to the parent `<Picker>` component.

The below assumes (as implied by your code) you are wanting to set the full product object as selected value, after which you can extract `productID`. If you explicitly want to set only the productID then you would need to pass `product.productID` to the value prop of the `<Picker.Item>` component and add a function to pass full product object to selectedValue prop of parent `<Picker>` component.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


const ProductPicker = () => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
  const [productDetails , setproductDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductList();
  }, []);

  const getProductList = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/customer/get-all-products", {

      method: "post",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authentication': `Bearer ${token}`
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setproductDetails(json.data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))

  };

  const renderProductList = () => {
    return productDetails.map((product) => {
      return <Picker.Item label={product.productName} value={product} />
    })
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        style={{height: 40, width: 150}}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
          setSelectedValue(itemValue);
        }}
      >
        {renderProductList()}

      </Picker>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default ProductPicker;
```